# Qt - meta object code

Tags: qt, meta

What do we mean by the `meta object code` when relating to the `Meta Object Compiler (moc)` in Qt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Meta objects enhance programming languages by creating new or manipulate existing objects. They provide functionalities a language does not actually have by itself. The Meta Objects are interpreted either by compile time or run time. In Qt and C++ it is done during compile time by the Meta Object Compiler (moc).

An example case is the usage of the signal/slot concept.

Comment: Regards to the signal/slot example, does it mean that when there is a Q_OBJECT macro in a class, the code behind the macro provides a signal/slot mechanism for the class OR the code to handle signals and slots will be generated?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically asked about `Meta object` and `moc`,

From [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html#moc),

> ...The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source file containing the meta-object code for those classes. ...

HTH..

Comment: I think meta-object code means generated .moc files.

Answer (score 0):

Meta object code is required for Signal Slot mechanism ,Run time type information and dynamic property system.

Answer (score -4):

Qt system creates "meta object code" based on "annotations" in your c++ code (eg Q_PROPERTY, Q_SLOTS etc). Qt uses them to implement meta-calls and reflection style access to class properties.

Look at the ".moc" files that the compiler produces for your class and you'll understand.

But given the uncertainty around Qt's future, may I ask why you are choosing Qt? (unless its purely for the joy of hacking..)

Comment: Any need for the FUD at the end of your comment?

Comment: "FUD"? I think you should be reading a little more news. I'm not sure you can find two people who would recommend using Qt for a new commercial project at this point. Like I said, if its for personal use, Qt is more than useful.

Comment: The slashdot community disagrees with your FUD too. http://news.slashdot.org/story/11/05/31/202238/Free-Software-Faces-a-Test-With-Qt